# Вызов статического метода Class.forName в jni(ndk)

Tags: android, android-ndk, jni

Получение класса `java/lang/Class` в jni и `GetStaticMethodID` прошло успешно, но вызов CallStaticObjectMethod падает с ошибкой `CALL_STATIC_TYPE...`

Вызываю так:

```
jclass Class = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
jmethodId forNameMethodId = env->GetStaticMethodId(Class,"forName","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;");
jstring classname = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(Class, methodId, "com.*.*.ClassName");
```

Comment: `jstring classname`!? Метод `forName` ведь должен вернуть класс (`jclass` то есть), а Вы ждёте и так известное Вам имя в виде строки. И зачем это всё? Почему не сразу: `jclass clazz = env->FindClass("com/*/*/ClassName");` и т.д.?

Comment: @woesss Но мне нужно проверить, существует ли определённый клас или нет, а если сделать так то бросает на код в файле jni.h...